# make json from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to make specific json from table. I have a table, which has rows and 4 columns. 
[Here is my **table**](http://jsfiddle.net/toshkaexe/bMzq8/) I want to build an jsonarray from the table.
First value in the  left  column is key of json and last value in the right column is a valueof json.

I mean I want to get from table jsonarray, it must look as

```
json_from_form = [{color: 'id', 
          name: "mouse",
          x: "table",
          y: "book"}];
```

I have tried to build json, but have a problem with  structure and setting a key in json object.
Please help me to buld right structure of json object.

```
var json_from_form_tmp = {};
$('#table').find('tbody tr').each(function (i) {
    //var name = $(this).find('td:first').text(); 
    json_from_form_tmp[i] = {
        imd: $(this).find('td:eq(3) input').val()
    };
});
console.log(json_from_form_tmp);
```

[Here is my **DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/toshkaexe/bMzq8/)

Comment: check this link http://jsfiddle.net/dGPks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the jQuery [map-function](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for this, here is an example:

```
$(function () {    
    var m = $("table tr").map(function (index, e) {        
        return {
            color: $(e).children().eq(0).text(),
            name: $(e).children().eq(1).text()
        }
    }).get();
});
```

Where m will be an array of objects as defined inside the map function.

Answer (score 0):

To set a property of the object (json_from_form_tmp), use the ['propertyName'] notation.

```
//get the name of the property from the first column     
var name = $(this).find('td:first').text();

//use that name as the name of the property. Your value fetch was right!
json_from_form_tmp[name] = $(this).find('td:eq(3) input').val();
```

Here is your fiddle with a tiny modification.

http://jsfiddle.net/bMzq8/32/